# Encoding for an XML document containing U+001A

Tags: xml, unicode

I have an XML document that's being generated from some content that people are copy/pasting from all sorts of places (Word documents mostly though).

It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <data> <![CDATA[
         (whatever was pasted)
    ]]></data>        
</response>
```

I've always used an encoding of `UTF-8` or `iso-8859-1`, but now someone's gone and copy/pasted the unicode character [`U+001A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1a/index.htm) (`0x1a`) and I can't find an encoding that will accept it. Everything I put the XML file into (e.g. Firefox, Internet Explorer, XML Spy) all say it's invalid, regardless of the kind of encoding used.

Is there an encoding I can use that will stop the file from falling over, or do I need to start stripping all these characters out one by one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

U+001A is not a valid character in an XML document.  The valid range of characters according to [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) is:

```
Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF] /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */
```

Comment: Not what I was hoping to hear, but thanks. Looks like another thing that's "Surely very quick to fix" is going to turn into another long day.

Answer (score 5):

The character U+001A is in the C0 Controls area, which is mostly (including U+001A) forbidden in XML. It is improbable that anyone entered it on purpose. Rather, it was generated by software, probable when performing character code conversion and detecting malformed data (e.g., a byte that has no defined meaning in the source encoding). The U+001A (SUBSTITUTE) character is meant for such use; see my [quick reference to C0 Controls](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html).

If you cannot track down and fix the conversion (or other process) that produced the U+001A, I’d suggest that you replace it by U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER. It’s in a sense the Unicode equivalent of U+001A. (The latter is of course in Unicode too, but disallowed in many contexts.) However it has a visible glyph, though the glyph exists in a few fonts only; check the [fileformat.info entry on U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) for more info.

The point here is that changing U+001A to U+FFFD makes the data acceptable in XML and still retains the information about character-level data error.

Answer (score 2):

Preprocess the original data, encoding Unicode characters not supported by XML documents yourself.  for example, use HTML character encodings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <data> <![CDATA[This is &#x1a; a test.]]></data>        
</response>
```

You'll have to post-process the data when read back in to convert the HTML encoding back to the correct Unicode character.

Comment: This helped me to get the idea of already replacing the value during the sql query with a sql replace(). By this, I could exclude this strange character. It crashed my Python as soon as the Python compiler read it in the code when I replaced it in Python instead, I had to reload codium and get the virtual environment back. Seems to be an alien among even the strange characters, since my code could utf-8 handle non-Latin letters, but not this one.