# Getting SAXParseException while parsing a xml file

Tags: java, alfresco, sax

In java i am crating a XMLstring and that string contains some special character. Then i am sending these xml string to alfresco's executeAction to create a word document. But it's throwing this SAXParseException.

"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 99; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1a) was found in the element content of the document."

Special char in my string is !"#$%&'()*+,-./09:;<=>?@AZ[]^_`ayz{|}~?‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹Œ?Ž??‘’“”•–˜™š›œ?žŸ¡¢£¥?§?©ª«¬­®¯°±²³?µ·?¹º»Àãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ

Comment: please share your code, what are you sending and what are you expecting?

Comment: @vmrvictor I am sending a xml document with these special characters to alfresco's executeAction to create a word document. I want these special character in my word document. But it's throwing the above said exception.

Comment: Issue is in inverted commas. Refer the following thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml).

Comment: I already tried with these but it not works

Comment: I also used StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(), It replace all the invalid characters. But when alfresco creating the word document the scpecial characters are not showing properly

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically remove the 0x1a character with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505816/streamexception-an-invalid-xml-character-unicode-0x1a) before submitting it to the executeAction method.