# How to ignore invalid xml response with Spring's JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, xml, spring, jax-ws, jaxb2

I am using the JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean to create a simple ws client from a wsdl. Everything works as expected but unfortunately the response I am getting contains unicode characters which are invalid in xml documents. Unfortunately this is a third-party web service and the owner cannot change the content currently.
Consequently I am getting exceptions like the following:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1563]
Message: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1a) was found in the element content of the document.
```

Is there anyway to ignore these errors, receive the response and clear it out myself? If not, is there any "proper" or "usual" way to handle with these kinds of situations?

Thanks

Comment: "I am getting contains unicode characters which are invalid in xml documents." - This is totally incorrect. XML can have unicode characters.

Comment: I probably wrote it wrong (excuse my english). I meant that the response contains some invalid unicode characters for xml. Exactly what Pangea below mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that 0x1a is NOT in the [valid character set range for XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Char). May be [this solution](http://blog.mark-mclaren.info/2007/02/invalid-xml-characters-when-valid-utf8_5873.html) is what you are looking for i.e. removing the invalid character your self using some sort of filter/interceptor may be..

Also, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425761/encoding-for-an-xml-document-containing-u001a/8427929#8427929) for another alternate solution which is to replace it with the UNICODE Replacement character.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I don't know if there is a way to filter the response before it gets parsed and the exception is thrown. Could you maybe point me to the right direction on how to use such an interceptor before using the JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean? Thanks!

Comment: @gpol I am pretty sure spring supports interceptors for WS clients (e.g. validating interceptor http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/02/28/spring-ws-client/). I haven't used it myself though. So ask 1 more question in SO and u will get answers. Also, if this question is the answer then accept it.